# Recursion codes for quick sort

Tags: c++

Here below is a function I am struggling with, which is defined for quick sorting based on recursion operations:

```
void quick_sort(QVector<RoiInfo> &roi, int begin, int end)
{
  int     i, j;
  int     pivot;
  RoiInfo work;
  int     half = (begin+end)/2;

  pivot = roi[half].roi.y;
  i = begin;
  j = end;

  //I am confused about the codes below, what kind of sorting it is to do
  while( 1 )
  {
    while( roi[i].roi.y > pivot ){ ++i; }
    while( roi[j].roi.y < pivot ){ --j; }
    if( i >= j ){ break; }


    work = roi[i];
    roi[i] = roi[j];
    roi[j] = work;

    i++;
    j--;
  }

  if( begin < i - 1 ){ quick_sort( roi, begin, i - 1 ); }
  if( j + 1 < end ){ quick_sort( roi, j + 1, end ); }
}
```

In the above codes, the `RoiInfo` is a user-defined class, which has a public member of `roi` of `CvRect` type, which is a OpenCV class defining a rectangle specified by `(x, y, width, height)`. Any one can explain to me, preferably with an example, what is going on for the `quick_sort` function? Much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like a normal [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm) to me? Pick an item as your 'pivot'; sort things into less than the pivot and greater than the pivot, then recurse into the below-pivot and above-pivot portions, provided there's more than one item in each..

Comment: @Rup: thank you for pointing out the link to me! Very informative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it sorting by `y` coordinates ?! (I couldn’t comment.) Comparison is done only on the `y` coordinates, apparently it sorts the rectangles from top to bottom.

The following does the partitioning for quick-sort.

```
while( roi[i].roi.y > pivot ){ ++i; }
while( roi[j].roi.y < pivot ){ --j; }
```

And we recurse into a smaller sub-problems if there are still elements left on the left or right side.

```
if( begin < i - 1 ){quick_sort( roi, begin, i - 1 );} //elements to the left
if( j + 1 < end ){quick_sort( roi, j + 1, end );} //elements to the right
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you with sorting for y coordinates. "from bottom to top" implies sorting in an ascending order?

Comment: @jingweimo. Sorry for the wrong answer (I have edited it now). Since elements greater than the pivot go to the left, it sorts them in descending order (highest `y` coordinate first).